# How to install and use vim without messing up with write mode

Tags: ubuntu-touch, vim, phone

The terminal app works fine, I can run `vi` using it. The problem is that I've already get used to `vim` and don't want to learn all the vi-vim differences just for editing plaintext. I assume there must be a way to use such common tool like `vim` without messing with *write-mode* on Ubuntu Phone, but I cannot see `vim` app in app center.
I have Ubuntu 14.10 (r22) and bq Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition.

Comment: Can you access terminal? If so run `sudo apt-get install vim` to install `vim` @jangorecki

Comment: AFAIK `apt-get install` requires ubuntu phone to turn partition into *write-mode*, isn't that true?

Comment: Sorry I don't know _too_ much about ubuntu phone I was just giving it a shot :)

Comment: But maybe you can build it from source on your own